# Null vs empty collections in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Say I have the following Hibernate-mapped class:

```
public class ClassA {       
   @OneToMany(fetch=EAGER)
   private List<ClassB> bList;
}
```

When I read an object of `ClassA` from a Hibernate session, the `bList` field is initialized with a `PersistentList` object, as expected.

I find myself with a requirement where in situations where the list is empty, I need Hibernate to initialize the `bList` field to `null`, rather than with an empty `PersistentList`. In theory, Hibernate has the information it needs to do this, since the fetch on the list is eager. The problem is that according to [section 6.1 of the Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-synopsis):

> Collection-valued properties do not support null value semantics because Hibernate does not distinguish between a null collection reference and an empty collection.

This makes perfect sense, but I'm hoping someone can come up with a cunning ruse to overcome this limitation. I'm thinking perhaps some listener/callback mechanism might allow me to replace empty lists with null references.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried to check in the getbList() method?  You could do:

```
if(bList.isEmpty()) 
    return null;
return bList;
```

Hibernate will always create an object for your references, but you are allowed to control the data inside of the getter and setters.  If the list has 0 elements you can always return null.

Comment: I think this may end up being the simplest solution, yes

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious why you consider this a "limitation' - does a null `bList` actually have a different *meaning* to your application than an empty `bList`?

I think that in most areas, a null collection and an empty collection have the same semantic meaning, which I would guess is why the Hibernate developers sought to limit Hibernate to only using one. Doesn't make much sense to always check `if (bList == null || bList.isEmpty)` if the two always end up meaning the same thing.

Comment: It most situations, you'd be correct, but the clients of this particular object model distinguish between null and empty, and I have no control over that.

Answer (score 2):

For handling in your code the obvious way is in the getter, however that doesn't help you if you want to evaluate it in HQL.

Two ideas:

- A constructor that sets it to NULL if
  empty.
- A `@PostLoad / @PostConstruct` method
  that does the same.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of @PostLoad, I'm liking that. How does it interact with @PostConstruct?